# unity5 - iTween Null Reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I use `iTween` a lot and it was OK for most of the time until yesterday, I am getting and error suddenly:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
iTween.RetrieveArgs () (at Assets/Plugins/Pixelplacement/iTween/iTween.cs:6811)
iTween.Awake () (at Assets/Plugins/Pixelplacement/iTween/iTween.cs:6559)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(Object, Vector3, Quaternion)`

Initially every time I start the game I get 320 calls of these errors but later it accumulates to 720 and now 999+. I am not sure why  it accumulate even though I start the game from scratch all together. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE:**

To an extend, I believe it is due to `Sourcetree` that I use for version control. I believe it somehow mess up the meta file or make unity have some sort of conflict internally while looking at `iTween.cs`.

Comment: Since there are different possible versions of iTween (with different line numbers), can you post the code where NullReferenceException happens?

Comment: I redownload the latest version and still same problem persist, this is line 6811:`id=(string)tweenArguments["id"];` and this is line 6559:`RetrieveArgs();` and my code that affected:`GameObject instance2 = (GameObject)Instantiate(manprefab,new Vector3(j*3f, 50f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));`, which doesn't have anything to do with `iTween`.

Comment: Wait, what "my code that affected" means? What exactly is the connection between this error and this line of your code?

Comment: There is no connection at all. but when console present the error it give me these 3 lines. that is why i don't understand.

Comment: I see. I suspect that the object you're instantiating has an `iTween` component on it, am I correct? Then, of course the instantiation would result in `Awake` call.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error. I found out that by some bug in iTween it had dynamically added multiple iTween script components to one of my prefabs. As soon as I removed them, my errors disappeared.

I suggest you go through your prefabs

Answer (score 0):

The order of **script execution** in Unity could be the problem. I had this problem days ago and the solution was to go to

**Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Script Execution Order**

then put the script that is been accessed from iTween.cs:6559 to run first. I was getting the same error randomly but they longer appear once I did it. Hopefully that will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you give more detail example?

Comment: The error is coming from iTween.cs. What function/class is been called where this error is coming from. If the error is coming from  Assets/Plugins/Pixelplacement/iTween/iTween.cs:6811 ?  Open that the iTween code and go to line 6811. Look for a function that is been called from this line. If the fuction is DoSomething.exit(), then you know that the DoSomething is the class name. Go to Edit->Project Settings->Script Execution Order and make DoSomething class to be the first script to in the execution order.



Do the same thing to Assets/Plugins/Pixelplacement/iTween/iTween.cs:6559

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to cost more problem. I believe it has to do with .meta data since it accumulate even I restart `Unity3d`.

Comment: I still stand with the script execution idea. You want to post the line of code at (at Assets/Plugins/Pixelplacement/iTween/iTween.cs:6811)  and  (at Assets/Plugins/Pixelplacement/iTween/iTween.cs:6559)?

Comment: If your code correctness relies on such external factors as script execution order, it's prone to break in the future again, and debugging would be a pain. I would rather investigate why exactly does script execution order matter here and remove this implicit dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I had the same reason for the bug but this is how I solved it.

The objects I was running the itween on, were in the scene. When I made sure that the references I was using to invoke new instances were from a prefab and not references to objects in the scene - it worked.

Answer (score -1):

In the `Awake` function, 
iTween.Init (every object on the itween is applied), as [documented by the PixelPlacement](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/documentation.php)